# jQuery not posting to server successfully

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Here is my action code, this currently only allows GET for testing purposes

```
//[HttpPost]
public JsonResult BuildingBookings(string buildingName)
{
        var result = new BuildingBookings_Result(); //This has a breakline on it
        //Uninteresting code to populate result
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The first line of my ASP MVC has a breakpoint on it, I can trigger this for testing purposes using the following URL in a browser

```
http://localhost:22468/Buildings/Bookings?buildingName=DoesNotExist
```

And the expected result is returned

```
{"Success":false,"Message":"Building not found","Data":[]}
```

But when I try to do exactly the same thing from jQuery the breakpoint in my ASP MVC action is never triggered.  This is the same whether I use GET or correct all of the relevant code to use POST instead.

```
//Source code in browser using Ajax
<script>
        $("#MainForm").submit(
                function () {
                        alert("Calling");
                        $.ajax({
                                url: "http://localhost:22468/Buildings/Bookings",
                                data: { buildingName: "DoesNotExist" },
                                type: "GET",
                                success: function (result) {
                                        alert("Call OK");
                                        alert("Status " + result.Success);
                                        alert("Message" + result.Message);
                                        alert("Building name " + result.Data.Name);
                                        alert("Sleeps " + result.Data.Sleeps.toString());
                                },
                                error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
                                        alert("Call Fail");
                                        alert("status " + status);
                                        alert("request " + request.toString());
                                        alert("error " + errorThrown.toString());
                                }
                        });
                        return false;
                });
</script>
```

I get the "Calling" alert, followed by "Call fail", Status = "Error"

UPDATE: This is not a CORS issue as I have added the appropriate header to the response to permit cross domain calls.  The code works with a GET, but not with POST or jsonp as the $.ajax type (obviously I put [HttpPost] back in first)

Answer (score 0):

If you html file is opened in file:// or is obtained from another domain/port, you have a security exception because that's a cross-domain query.

The most common solution is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Another one is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) (I had compatibility problems in the past with this solution but if you use only modern browsers you should be fine).

Comment: I am using http://localhost as the client.  The Access-Control-Allow-Origin solves the problem when I am using GET, but not JSONP